# MySQL: error 1118 (42000) row size too large

Tags: mysql, mysqldump, myisam, errors

1. storage_engine = **MyISAM**
2. table_type = **MyISAM**
3. version = **5.1.25-rc**

**database_name.sql** dump size is **3.3G**:

```
mysqldump -u user -p database_name > database_name.sql
```

When I try to restore the database (trying to restore on MySQL 5.1.25-rc and on 5.7.17):

```
mysql -u user -p database_name < database_name.sql
```

...an error:

> *ERROR 1118 (42000) at line 7192: Row size too large. The maximum row size for the used table type, not counting BLOBs, is 65535. You have to change some columns to TEXT or BLOBs*

"Questions that may already have your answer" doesn't have answer for me :(

Comment: Are you using the same character set as on the source database?

Comment: @Philᵀᴹ Yes, it same.

Comment: can you post the create table statement for the table (from database_name.sql file) that import is failing for?

Answer (score 0):

Sounds like the import forced the Engine to be InnoDB??

If so, then let's see the my.cnf and figure out what to fix.

If not, then let's see the `CREATE TABLE` that is leading to the problem.

Or, maybe, a `CHARACTER SET` default changed.

Show us the first part of the dump and the `CREATE TABLE` just before the naughty table.